# Create an Array that allows users to input data up to 3 times but each input can be done separately instead of completing it at a go

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, arraylist

How do i create an array that allows users to input their name at different interval. 
Currently i am required to enter all the names at once to fill up the array. And upon filling up the array with names , once i choose to input data new names into the name array, the previous keyed in information disappears.

What i hope to achieve:
1) to allow users to key in one name at a time and exit back to main menu instead of requiring to fill up the whole name array.

2) Upon entering the first name, when i attempt to key in another new name in the second interval, the existing name i key before remains and the second name will be stored in position 2 instead of 1.

code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.*;
 public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {

       Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
       int[] values = new int[3];
       int[] pNumber= new int[3];
       String[] name= new String[3];
       //double[] height= new double[25];
       //double[] weight=new double[25];
       char choose;
       do
       {
           displayMenu();
           String choice=console.nextLine();
           choose=choice.charAt(0);
           switch(choose)
           {
               case '1' : queuePatient(pNumber,name);
               //case '1' : queuePatient(studentNumber,name,height,weight);
                          break; 
              /*case '2' : callNextPatient(pNumber,name);
                          break;
               case '3' : listPatients(pNumber,name);
                          break;
               case '4' : searchPatient(pNumber,name);
                          break; */   
               case '0' : System.out.println("Exit");  
                          break;     
               default : System.out.println("Invalid");
                         break; 
           }
       }while(choose!='0');
       System.exit(0);
    }
   private static void displayMenu()
   {
        System.out.println("\n Menu: "); 
        System.out.println("1. Queue a Patient: "); 
        System.out.println("2. Call Next Patient: "); 
        System.out.println("3. List Patients in Queue: ");
        System.out.println("4. Search A Patient's Queue Position ");
        System.out.println("0. Exit ");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: "); 
   }


    private static void queuePatient(int[] pNumber,String[] name)
     {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);


        for(int i = 0 ;i <= 3;i++)
               {   
                   if(i==3){
               System.out.println("Queue is full."); 
                 break; 
                           } 
                System.out.println("Patient Number " + (i+1));
                System.out.print("Enter the Patient Name: \n");
                name[i] = kb.nextLine();

                  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
                  break;

                }
      }


    }


/*

private static void callNextPatient(String[] pNumber,String[] name)
{
  System.out.println("S/No  " + "Queue No   " + "Patient Name \t \t \t" );
        for(int n=0;n<25;n++)
        {
            if(!pNumber[n].equals("END"))
            {

 System.out.println((n+1) +"\t"+ pNumber[n] +"\t" + name[n]+"\t"+ "\t"+ "\t");
            }
            else
            break;
}

private static void listPatients(String[] pNumber,String[] name)
   {
        System.out.println("S/No  " + "Queue No   " + "Patient Name \t \t \t" );
        for(int n=0;n<25;n++)
        {
            if(!pNumber[n].equals("END"))
            {

 System.out.println((n+1) +"\t"+ pNumber[n] +"\t" + name[n]+"\t"+ "\t"+ "\t");
            }
            else
            break;
        }
    }

private static void searchPatient(String[] pNumber,String[] name)
{
  System.out.println("S/No  " + "Queue No   " + "Patient Name \t \t \t" );
        for(int n=0;n<25;n++)
        {
            if(!pNumber[n].equals("END"))
            {

 System.out.println((n+1) +"\t"+ pNumber[n] +"\t" + name[n]+"\t"+ "\t"+ "\t");
            }
            else
            break;
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList.

To create an ArrayList, do the following:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayName = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To add an element to that array, do the following:

```
arrayName.add("new element");
```

You can learn more about them here: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/array_lists.html

Comment: Dear Connorelsea,

I am grateful for your reply. But i can't seem to understand what you mean. i will read up on what you say. I have tried different ways for 4 days already but don't seem to solve or get any closer to my objective. 
I have attached my code above, can you advise me in anyway .

Sincerely,

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. If you want to use a normal array then simply access its elements by doing "variablename[x] = "new name" " where x is the number of the index where you want to edit. If you could provide a clearer question then maybe I could help? I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: I am required to carry an array that maintains a list of up to 25 patients. 
patient names are stored in the queue and the system will allow the clinic staff to perform the
following tasks:
- Queue a Patient

Comment: The method queuePatient()queues a patient.
This method receives as the parameters: the array of names, patient name and a count that keeps track of the number of patients queuing in the system. If queue is full, the method displays a message Queue is full.If queue has not reached full capacity, the method should put the name of the patient into the queue, update the count and displays a message in this format: name is in position #n where name is the patient name entering the queue and n is a number starting from 1.